# Yii cant transmit variable to layout

Tags: php, yii

im newbie in Yii and have some troubles.
My first problem:
My view displays nothing.

View(news/index.php):

```
<p>Hi</p>
```

Second problem:
I can't transmit variable from database to my layout(layouts/main.php) or view (watch first problem).
My controller:

```
<?php

   class NewsController extends Controller
   {

    public function actionIndex()
    {  

    $result = News::model()->findAll('id');
    $this->render('index', array('result'=>$result));
    }


}
```

from main.php (layouts/main.php):

```
<div id = "content">
    <?php 
    echo $content;
    echo $result; //or $this->mydatafrombase;
    ?>
    </div>
```

Or im trying to get variable in view news/index.php:

```
<p>Hi</p>
<?php
echo $this->mydatafrombase;
?>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Don't use `$this` to access the variables from the controller. You can access them by just adding a `$`: `'result'` becomes `$result` in your view.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is $result variable at layout is wrong.

1.If you want use $result at layout. You must make a global variable at NewsController. And set value for it at action.

**Controller:**

```
<?php
    //controller: NewsController 
    class NewsController extends Controller
    {
      public $result;

      public function actionIndex(){
        $this->result = News::model()->findAll();
        $this->render('index');
      }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<!-- layout.php-->
<div id="content">
<?php 
   echo $content; //content of view of your action will be render at here
   var_dump($this->result); // variable global of class NewsController
?>
</div>
```

2.If you want user $result variable at view of your action

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class NewsController extends Controller
{
   public function actionIndex(){

     $result = News::model()->findAll();
     $this->render('index', array('result'=>$result));
   }
} ?>
```

**View:**

```
<!-- news/index.php -->
<p>Hi</p>
<?php
    var_dump($result);
?>

<!-- layout.php.-->
<div id="content">
<?php 
   echo $content; //content of view of your action will be render at here
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help.Your first suggestion works fine, but i have no idea how to execute data from this array. For example, news_title. And 2nd suggestion not works, i don't now why, maybe because im using not default layout?

Comment: you don't using default layout?.. $layout is a property of CController Class. Therefore you can define them at your action: $this->layout = 'new'. file view: layouts/new.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want a layout to load a value from variable. And if a user is logged in.

You can use CWebUser::setState() and CWebUser::getState();

CController::render() only pass variable into index.php.

in your case. It would be simply to put $result into index.php

```
<?php
echo $result;//echo $this->mydatafrombase;
//yes simply $result would work. not $this->result. $this in this context refer to NewsController.
?>
```